# Django post_save signal not working properly

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

In my `models.py` file, I have a class named `OrderPayment`, now whenever I create a new object of `OrderPayment`, I want to also create a `Transaction` object. Am trying to do this with `post_save` signal but it not working. Below is how the code looks

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=OrderPayment)
def orderpayment_setup(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print(instance.order.dispatch_rider.company)
    print(instance)
    wt = Transaction.objects.create(
        wallet=Wallet.objects.get(user=instance.order.dispatch_rider.company),
        amount=instance.amount,
        description="Dispatch Order",
        status='success',
        transaction_type='deposit'
    )
    print(wt)
```

The `orderpayment_setup` function gets triggered but the `Transaction` object is not created. I also sees the first two `print` statement but I don't see the last one.

I don't know what I'm not doing right

Comment: Have you checked if **Wallet.objects.get(user=instance.order.dispatch_rider.company)** return an object ?

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html  read the tutorial, hope you will understand.

Comment: I think your signal function is outside models.py (ex: signals.py), in this case you need to import apps.py 

read `Where should this code live` section https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions